# What kind of server rack is this? (Type and possible manufacturer)

Tags: rack

I'm not sure what kind of server rack this is or what to call it (half-height, open/etc.) When identifying this rack in the field, what would you call it as a description to someone over the phone?

Does anyone recognize it or possibly even know its model and manufacturer?

[image: Server Rack (Unknown)]

Comment: according to [this](https://www.server-racks.com/rack-types.html) is this server an 'Open Frame' rack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## iStarUSA WO22AB 22U 4 Post Open Frame Rack

[image: iStarUSA WO22AB 22U 4 Post Open Frame Rack]

[Link to site here](https://www.goharddrive.com/iStarUSA-WO22AB-22U-4-Post-Open-Frame-Rack-p/g08-0016.htm)

Answer (score 0):

With the casters that looks like a rack designed for audio equipment, rather than servers, an "[*Amp Rack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp_rack)",  "*audio equipment rack*",  "*DJ rack*" or "*studio rack*"

"Professional" audio gear comes in the same [19'' rack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19-inch_rack) form factor as rack mounted servers and telecom gear.  Racks designed and marketed for housing audio equipment can be used for servers and vice versa server cabinets can be used to house 19'' audio equipment.